# setting cookie to null not working in java

Tags: java, html, cookies, session-cookies, setcookie

i want to remove cookie with domain name and context path as "/" which is running in my cloud server.

i have below code for clearing cookie in cloud server

```
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, null);// cookieName = TEST_COOKIE
    String cookiePath = request.getContextPath();
    cookie.setPath(cookiePath); // path = "/"
    cookie.setDomain("mydomain.com");
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
```

if i notice the cookie in my browser i have below details

```
cookie name = "TEST_COOKIE"  value  = "MUZJd3NuNDhy"  domain = "mydomain.com" path = "/"
```

where in my localhost, above code works fine, without setting domain name. even i tried with empty domain name which is not working. dont know how to proceed with this, direction is much appreciated.

EDIT - 
below code without domain in localhost is working fine with context path as /MyApp.

```
    Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, null);
    String cookiePath = request.getContextPath();
    cookie.setPath(cookiePath); // path = "/"
    cookie.setMaxAge(0);
    response.addCookie(cookie);
```

when i removed contextPath "/MyApp", it stopped working in localhost too, where in my cloud server my context path is "/" .

Comment: Have you tried setting non-null value, but still with `setMaxAge(0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lot of debugging, i found the request.getContextPath was returning empty string instead of "/" in my remote server, and in jave doc

```
 * Returns the portion of the request URI that indicates the context
 * of the request. The context path always comes first in a request
 * URI. The path starts with a "/" character but does not end with a "/"
 * character. For servlets in the default (root) context, this method
 * returns "". The container does not decode this string.
```

since i am having root context , the method return empty string instead of "/", i have fixed it by below code and it is working now.

```
    if (cookiePath.isEmpty()) {
        cookie.setPath("/");
    } else {
        cookie.setPath(cookiePath);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot set a `Cookie` as `null` but you can delete it (i.e. : when you'll try to get it next time, it will return null).

Just change your first line with :

```
Cookie cookie = new Cookie(cookieName, "");
String cookiePath = request.getContextPath();
cookie.setPath(cookiePath); // path = "/"
cookie.setDomain("mydomain.com");
cookie.setMaxAge(0);
response.addCookie(cookie);
```

Comment: not working mate..the piece of code working in local, but it is not working in cloud